# RM over SSL with single port on server

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, rmi

**CASE 1 - WITHOUT SSL**
When I a need a simple RMI connection (without SSL) I use the following code on server

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2004,rmiClientSocketFactory,rmiServerSocketFactory);
stub=UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(someObj, 2004, rmiClientSocketFactory,rmiServerSocketFactory);
```

Please, pay attention that I use port number both when create registry and when exporting object. The code works as expected - no any problems.

**CASE 2 - WITH SSL**
I use the same code as in case 1 only both factories are SSL factories. Result - on server side one socket is created on port 2004 but my client can't connect to it - it throws

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:248)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at rmi.DateClient.perform(DateClient.java:48)
    at rmi.DateClient.main(DateClient.java:38)
Exception occured: java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
```

To make it work I need to modify my code on server to

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2004);
stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(someObj, 0, rmiClientSocketFactory, rmiServerSocketFactory);
```

This code works but on server side two sockets are created one on port 2004 and one on some variable port (for example 45329). But I don't want to have two sockets. How to explain and fix it?

Comment: @JarrodRobertson Fixed your edit. SSL doesn't do port sharing. Only RMI does that. The title doesn't make sense without RMI in it somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To make it work I need to modify my code on server to

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(2004);
```

No. That's a backwards step: you're removing SSL from the Registry. You need to modify your *client* to use SSL when looking up the Registry. That means you have to use the `Registry` class instead of `Naming`:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(host, 2004, rmiClientSocketFactory);
MyRemoteInterface mri = (MyRemoteInterface)registry.lookup(...);
```

In any case you can't have plaintext and SSL remote objects on the same port.