# SSL for JMX with RMI

Tags: java, ssl, rmi, jmx

We have a Java application which has had a JConsole connection with password authentication for a while. In improving the security of this, we are trying to encrypt the connection made from JConsole to the application.

Up until now, we have launched our application with the following launch command:

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=jmx.password \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=jmx.access \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
     -jar MyApplication.jar
```

With this, we can flawlessly access the JMX methods of MyApplication via both JConsole, jmxterm, and other Java applications. In JConsole and jmxterm, we can use both `hostname:1099` and `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostname:1099/jmxrmi` without issues. From the Java applications, we always use `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostname:1099/jmxrmi`, again without issues. Our application has no code-based setup of the JMX endpoint (we exposes some methods and attributes, but we did not touch the registry and socket factories).

Now we are trying to set up SSL between our application, and all other parties, following [www.cleantutorials.com/jconsole/jconsole-ssl-with-password-authentication](http://www.cleantutorials.com/jconsole/jconsole-ssl-with-password-authentication). Doing this, we have a keystore and truststore for both MyApplication and whoever the client connection to the JMX methods is. We use

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099 \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=jmx.password \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=jmx.access \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.registry.ssl=true \
     -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=hostname \
     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=server-jmx-keystore \
     -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password \
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=server-jmx-truststore \
     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password \
     -jar MyApplication.jar
```

After this, almost all our connections fail. The only one succeeding, is via JConsole (adding the client keystore and truststores to the launch config), and only using `hostname:1099`. Using the address `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostname:1099/jmxrmi` no longer works, not via JConsole, not via jmxterm, and not via other applications.

We have tried about any combination of launch settings we could think of, but nothing that we find anywhere seems to work. The error we see when trying to connect from e.g. jmxterm is:

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: non-JRMP server at remote endpoint
```

(I can provide the full stack if needed).

We're a bit at a loss on how to continue, what we can do to make all connections that used to work, now work. What should we do to enable connecting with `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostname:1099/jmxrmi`-like connection strings via SSL?

If relevant, this application is using OpenJDK 11.0.5, other applications where we might need this run on OpenJDK 8.

**Edit**

Debugging both the JConsole client and the backend side, it seems that the protocol that the client is trying to establish is not known in the SSL context. On the backend, we have the following error:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|20|RMI TCP Connection(1)|2021-12-28 10:04:04.265 CET|null:-1|Raw read (
  0000: 4A 52 4D 49 00
                JRMI.
)
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|20|RMI TCP Connection(1)|2021-12-28 10:04:04.267 CET|null:-1|Fatal (UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE): Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(Unknown Source)
          at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
          at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
          at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
          at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)}
)
```

After which the backend closes the connection.

Based on some tutorials online, it should be possible to get the SSL connection working using the service-based URL, but we can't get it to work.

Comment: Does your application in MyApplication.jar support SSL at all? That means does it use SSLServerSocket instead of ServerSocket?  'javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message' could be evidence for plaintext connection.

Comment: When connecting with hostname:1099, it does correctly make a handshake and connect without sending username/password in plaintext. I'm not sure if it's possible that the application supports SSL using one way, but not the other way. That said, we don't configure any specific Socket code-wise, the only configuration we do is with the JVM arguments.

Comment: You can try to set option -Djavax.net.debug=all and watch the console output. If there is any SSL debug output than your application uses SSL.

Comment: There is, that's where the logs are coming from.

Comment: Sorry, if my last question wasn't clear enough. Do you see (on either side) SSL handshake messages? First which must come is a CLIENT_HELLO (sent by client) imediately followed by a SERVER_HELLO (sent by server). If this messagese are sent, what is the last SSL handshake message before the exception?

Comment: I don't recall the client-side logs, but I don't think there's a CLIENT_HELLO or SERVER_HELLO in the logs on server-side logs. If I recall, the server-side logs are essentially what I put after the edit (first a list of ignored encryption algorithms, then the error/stack). Does that mean we have to add more setup in the code itself, to enable SSL via the service-URL? And if yes, what would that be? (A reference to some tutorial would also be sufficient to me, all tutorials I saw simply talk about the launch arguments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, with a lot of debugging, trial and error, we came to the conclusion that there is no out-of-the-box solution in Spring (Boot) to enable SSL with an RMI registry and a JMX connection server. This had to be configured manually. We used the following Spring configuration class that did the trick:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMBeanExport
public class JMXConfig {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(JMXConfig .class);

    @Value("${jmx.registry.port:1098}")
    private Integer registryPort;
    @Value("${jmx.rmi.port:1099}")
    private Integer rmiPort;

    @Bean
    public RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistry() {
        final RmiRegistryFactoryBean rmiRegistryFactoryBean = new RmiRegistryFactoryBean();
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setPort(rmiPort);
        rmiRegistryFactoryBean.setAlwaysCreate(true);

        LOG.info("Creating RMI registry on port " + rmiRegistryFactoryBean.getPort());
        return rmiRegistryFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("rmiRegistry")
    public ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean() throws MalformedObjectNameException {
        String rmiHost = getHost();
        String serviceURL = serviceURL(rmiHost);
        LOG.info("Creating JMX connection for URL " + serviceURL);

        final ConnectorServerFactoryBean connectorServerFactoryBean = new ConnectorServerFactoryBean();
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setObjectName("connector:name=rmi");
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setEnvironmentMap(createRmiEnvironment(rmiHost));
        connectorServerFactoryBean.setServiceUrl(serviceURL);
        return connectorServerFactoryBean;
    }

    private String getHost() {
        try {
            InetAddress localMachine = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            return localMachine.getCanonicalHostName();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            LOG.warn("Unable to get hostname, using localhost", e);
            return "localhost";
        }
    }

    private String serviceURL(String rmiHost) {
        return format("service:jmx:rmi://%s:%s/jndi/rmi://%s:%s/jmxrmi", rmiHost, registryPort, rmiHost, rmiPort);
    }

    private Map<String, Object> createRmiEnvironment(String rmiHost) {
        final Map<String, Object> rmiEnvironment = new HashMap<>();
        rmiEnvironment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContextFactory");
        rmiEnvironment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "rmi://" + rmiHost + ":" + rmiPort);
        rmiEnvironment.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_CLIENT_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, new SslRMIClientSocketFactory());
        rmiEnvironment.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_SERVER_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, new SslRMIServerSocketFactory());
        return rmiEnvironment;
    }
}
```

This enables SSL using the connection details `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostname:1099/jmxrmi`. To make it work, you need to add a keystore/password to your backend, and a truststore/password to your frontend (as in the [tutorial](http://www.cleantutorials.com/jconsole/jconsole-ssl-with-password-authentication)).

Answer (score 1):

The thrown `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unsupported or unrecognized SSL message` is an indicator that there is plaintext instead of SSL communication. This asumption is verified by the fact that there are no SSL handshake messages (at least CLIENT_HELLO) in the debug output.
So it seems to be clear that th client doesn't use SSLSocket for communication.

One very simple example for SSLSocket based communication can be found here in [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/security/sample-code-illustrating-secure-socket-connection-client-and-server.htm#JSSEC-GUID-AA1C27A1-2CA8-4309-B281-D6199F60E666), but there are lot more available.

Comment: Based on your comment, I re-investigated and indeed, no SSL socket factory was used. Given all that I've read now, it appears that there is no default way to enable SSL via RMI in a Spring Boot setting. We have now activated the RmiRegistry and the JMXConnectionServer programmatically with the correct settings.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I'm not sure but if I read this [page from CERN](https://db-blog.web.cern.ch/blog/viktor-kozlovszky/2018-10-jmx-connection-ssl) correctly, and I quote:

> in case you don't use SSL the RMI port and the JMX port can be the same

it follows that if you want to use SSL/TLS you thus need to use 2 different ports on the server side. (This is confirmed by this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43615911/rm-over-ssl-with-single-port-on-server#comment74929758_43615911) stating: "SSL doesn't do port sharing").

Also you may want to consider using https://jolokia.org/ as HTTP+JSON alternative for all the crazyness of RMI networking, which also provides a Java client e.g. for JConsole, see the bottom of: https://jolokia.org/reference/html/clients.html for an example.

Comment: Thanks for this comment, I had observed this from trial and error, I'm glad that it indeed confirmed that we need two ports.
We will probably migrate to a HTTP endpoint in the future, since it appears Spring Boot is deprecating the RmiRegistry (and indeed, the networking is quite a bother).

Comment: It is a shame this limitation is not documented nor this combination of settings rejected at start-up, consider reporting a bug report to the Java bug database.

Answer (score 0):

TLS handshakes are obviously failing. Without knowing the contents of your truststore (a couple of self-signed certificates?), or the ability to inspect the certificates in exchange, it's most likely because `cacerts`, the default Java truststore that contains common public root certificates, is not being loaded anymore now that you're specifying your own truststore.

As a confidence check, you can import the contents of `cacerts` into a copy of your truststore and retry. (See keytool's importkeystore.)

Comment: I will try to add the contents of cacerts to the truststores tomorrow. In the meantime, I do find it strange that if this is the issue, that it does work when using the hostname:port URL, but not the service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://hostname:1099/jmxrmi URL. Then again, I am by no means an expert in these things, so it's likely that I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: Sadly, adding everything from cacerts to the truststores did not help.